# How to convert this _.each function that adds a key to each object into Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/4xfc4g3c/1/

**[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4)**

```
const spamData = [true, true, false];
const tweets   = [{ tweet: "Hello" }, { tweet: "World" }, { tweet: "Pork"}];

_.each(spamData, (value, i) => {
  tweets[i]['spam'] = value;
});

log(tweets);
```

---

Stuck at this point:

**[Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs)**

```
const setSpamValues = (spamValue) => {
    return spamValue;
};

R.forEach(setSpamValues, spamData);
```

Not sure what would be the best approach to now sent the returned `spamValue` to a new key named `spam` for each tweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also make use of [`R.zipWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) and [`R.assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) to achieve this.

```
const updatedTweets = R.zipWith(R.assoc('spam'), spamData, tweets);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that is some clean readable code :D the beauty of Ramda

Answer (score 3):

You should be in the habit of thinking about how to solve these problems on your own before leveraging on library to do it for you. If you're struggling with this elementary problem, you might want to reconsider your use of Ramda altogether. Once you understand the utility provided by Ramda, maybe then it makes sense to use it.

Here is the result you're looking for using nothing other than plain-old JavaScript.

```js
const spamData = [true, true, false];
const tweets   = [{ tweet: "Hello" }, { tweet: "World" }, { tweet: "Pork"}];

let result = tweets.map((t,i) =>
  Object.assign({}, t, {spam: spamData[i]})
);

console.log(result);
// [
//   {"spam": true, "tweet": "Hello"},
//   {"spam": true, "tweet": "World"},
//   {"spam": false, "tweet": "Pork"}
// ]
```

---

If you insist on using Ramda, you're probably looking for [`R.zip`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip)

```js
const spamData = [true, true, false];
const tweets   = [{ tweet: "Hello" }, { tweet: "World" }, { tweet: "Pork"}];

let result = R.zip(spamData, tweets).map(([spam, tweet]) =>
  Object.assign({}, tweet, {spam})
);

console.log(result);
// [
//   {"spam": true, "tweet": "Hello"},
//   {"spam": true, "tweet": "World"},
//   {"spam": false, "tweet": "Pork"}
// ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

ps, next time you ask a question you should include the expected output.

---

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed albeit douchy answer, after reviewing both looks like lodash still ends up being the most readable version.

Comment: *"douchy answer"* – wtf? The use of `_.each` forces you to mutate `tweets` to get your desired output. If you're going to stay with lodash, you should use `_.map`.